# How do I return from a bash function on error?

Tags: bash, shell

I am writing a bash function.

How do I make the control exit the function as soon as any command in it error out?

I have tried this:

```
function myFunc() {
    set +e
    cmd1
    cmd2
    set -e
}
```

It works but it closes my terminal as well.

Appreciate any ideas.

Thanks.

Comment: `cmd1 || return; cmd2 || return`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"exit" means exit the shell. If you want to return from the function, you need to "return", which you can only do manually:

```
myFunc() {
  cmd1 || return $?
  cmd2 || return $?
}
```

If you really want to use `set -e`, use a subshell as well:

```
myFunc () {
  (
    set -e
    cmd1
    cmd2
  ) || return $?
}
```

Also consider using `&&` to create a chain of commands each contingent on the success of the previous ones.

Answer (score 2):

Separate them by `&&`:

```
cmd1 && cmd2 && cmd3
```

Answer (score 0):

For truth tests without `set -e` one can test the value of `#?` to reveal the status of the last command:

```
#!/bin/bash


myfunc()
{
    true
    [ "$?" = "0" ] || return
    printf "passed truth test 1\n"

    true
    [ "$?" = "0" ] || return
    printf "passed truth test 2\n"

    false
    [ "$?" = "0" ] || return
    printf "passed false test\n"
}

myfunc

printf "passed continuation test\n"
```